# How to know the status of RDS using Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using RDS instance and I want to know the status of instance from AWS Lambda function written in Node.js

Comment: Sorry, but could you please clarify your question? Are you wanting to write an AWS Lambda function in Node.js that returns the status of an Amazon RDS instance? Please edit your question to show the code you have tried so far. You would presumably use [`describeDBClusters()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html#describeDBClusters-property).

Comment: please refer to the below link where i have uploaded the code and excepted output.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063715/how-to-take-rds-snapshot-status-as-input-in-aws-lambda-function-written-in-nodej

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`describeDBInstances()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html#describeDBInstances-property) method of the AWS SDK for Node.js. List of instance statuses can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Status.html