# How to take RDS Snapshot Status as input in AWS Lambda function written in Nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

In Params for the status variable what i have to write to take the status of snapshot as the input.

Expected Output:

Hello Team,
The manual Snapshot of RDS Instance has Started Successfully
        DB Instance         : mysql
        Region              : undefined
        Latest Snapshot     : mysql-test
        STARTED-TIME        : 11/26/2019, 3:03:52 PM
        status              : Creating
Thanks & Regards
AWS Lambda.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const awsConf = {
    region: process.env.REGION
};
const rdsConfig = {
    apiVersion: '2014-10-31',
    ... awsConf
};
const snsConfig = {
    apiVersion: '2010-03-31',
    ... awsConf
};
var rds = new AWS.RDS(rdsConfig);
var sns = new AWS.SNS(snsConfig);
function notifyUser(data, callback){
    const params = {
      Message: data.message, 
      Subject: data.subject,
      TopicArn: process.env.SNS_TOPIC_ARN
    };
    sns.publish(params, callback);
}
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
const params = {
    DBInstanceIdentifier: 'mysql', /* required */
    DBSnapshotIdentifier: 'mysql-test', /* DB Snapshot name */
    status: /*what to write here to take the status of snapshot as input*/
  };
function calcTime(city, offset) {
    var d = new Date();  
    var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
    return  nd.toLocaleString();
}
rds.createDBSnapshot(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        notifyUser({
            subject: "[AWS] RDS Manual Snapshot Failed",
            message: `
            Hello Team,
            The manual Snapshot of RDS Instance has been failed for the Following Reason.
                    DBINSTANCE      : ${params.DBInstanceIdentifier}
                    REGION          : ${awsConf.region}
                    ERROR           : ${err.stack}
                   FAILED-TIME      : ${calcTime('MUMBAI', '+5.5')}
        Thanks & Regards,
        AWS Lambda
            ` 
        }, callback) }
    else {
         notifyUser({
            subject: "[AWS] RDS Manual Snapshot Started",
            message: `
            Hello Team,
            The manual Snapshot of RDS Instance has Started Successfully
                    DB Instance         : ${params.DBInstanceIdentifier}
                    Region              : ${awsConf.region}
                    Latest Snapshot     : ${params.DBSnapshotIdentifier}
                    STARTED-TIME        : ${calcTime('MUMBAI', '+5.5')}
                    Status              : ${param.status}
        Thanks & Regards
        AWS Lambda
            ` 
        }, callback) } // successful response
  });
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Could you please edit your question and explain what you are wanting to do and what difficulty you are facing? I don't know what you mean by "take the status of snapshot as the input".

Comment: I think it's data.Status. have you tried ?

Comment: I want to create manual snapshot using aws lambda in specific period and send  2 mail like 1. Snapshot is in creating state 2.Snapshot has created successfully. How to do this

Comment: yes, i have tried data.status but it showing out as undefined.

Comment: Just wondering whether you have used "Status" or "status"

Comment: data.Status only i have used but it showing output as Undefiend

Comment: Can you please edit that code and send that which shows the snapshot status in output.

Comment: The data should have an attribute called "DBSnapshot" and it should contain Status. If it doesn't work log the data to see what it contains